# Shell script - loop through file names and extract numbers in the filename

Tags: shell, awk, sed

Using a linux shell script, I am trying to loop through all of the file names in a directory and extract the numbers out of the file name before I process the file.

Something like this:

```
for files in `ls *.gz`
do
        echo "Looking at...  $files"
        gunzip $files
        echo "$files" | awk '/[0-9]/' ' {print $1}'
        echo "$files is  unzipped"
done
```

Thank you for any help with this.

Comment: What's the problem with the current code you have?

Comment: The loop and the zipping are apparently unrelated to your question. Perhaps edit to focus on your actual problem.

Comment: The loop should obviously be `for files in *.gz`. The `ls` in backticks is not only superfluous, but potentially harmful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can substitute all non-numbers in the file name.

```
echo "${files//[!0-9]/}"
```

This will obviously produce concatenated numbers if a file name contains multiple runs of digits. For example, `12a34.gz` gets turned into `1234`.

This substitution mechanism is a Bash-only feature, and not supported by plain `sh`.

Comment: This gives me:  {LB_RPC_07042014.txt.gz//[!0-9]/}   {LB_RPC_07052014.txt.gz//[!0-9]/}   {LB_RPC_07062014.txt.gz//[!0-9]/}   {LB_RPC_07072014.txt.gz//[!0-9]/}

Comment: You seem to have the dollar sign in the wrong place.  That's `${` not `{$`.